# HLS live stream not play on Google nest hub 1 Gen

Tags: http-live-streaming, google-smart-home

1.The issue is reproduced 100% of the time.
2.device specific model and version information：

```
Google Nest Hub 1st Gen

Fushia version:16.20231130.3.59

Software version: 57.42.4.590278877

Chromecast firmware version:3.72.396338
```

3.The issue details:

- the request: "Intent: action.devices.EXECUTE,  Command: action.devices.commands.GetCameraStream".
- After the above request, the camera cloud service do respond the correct HLS stream URL information, but the google nest hub didn’t play the live stream.

However, if I use VLC player to play the same HLS stream URL,it works normal, google nest hub just show black screen with our device name on it.

-We follow the reference on the website: [Google home log reference](https://developers.home.google.com/codelabs/log-based-metrics#1), and check the log when Google home execute the command,It shows no error, and google home get response successfully.

1.The problem is very troublesome for us.
2.Have anybody met similar problems?   Can you give us some advice to solve this problem.